# Spring batch call stored procedure multiple time until get 0 rows

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch

How can I use spring batch for calling on ItemReader a stored procedure multiple times until get 0 rows.
For each time delegate the results of the stored procedure to ItemProcessor and ItemWriter?
The stored procedure is managing itself the offset on another table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in `ItemReader` implementation for that, you need a custom `ItemReader` that calls the stored procedure until it returns 0 results, in which case the reader would return `null` to signal the end of the data set.

The custom reader could delegate the procedure calling to the `StoredProcedureItemReader` provided by Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling writing custom reader for that. Can you give me an example how can I delegate each procedure output to the ItemProcessor?